# Prove or disprove $\sqrt{\frac{5a+8}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{5b+8}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{5c+8}{b+a}}\ge 2+2\sqrt{13}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

While solving a problem, I found that the following inequality which appears seem true but I can not prove it so far. It's

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove or disprove $$\color{black}{\sqrt{\frac{5a+8}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{5b+8}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{5c+8}{b+a}}\ge 2+2\sqrt{13}.   }$$
> I checked that if $a=b=1;c=0$ we get an equality and didn't find an example that makes my prediction wrong.

I tried to homogenize $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{5a+8\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{b+c}}\ge 2+2\sqrt{13}.$$
Also, I thought of isolated fudging. See [Yufei Zhao's file](https://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/wc08/ineq.pdf)
$$\sqrt{\frac{5a+8\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{b+c}}\ge (2+2\sqrt{13})\cdot\frac{xa^2+y(b^2+c^2)+mbc+n(ab+ac)}{a^2+b^2+c^2+k(ab+bc+ca)}.$$Unfortunately, I got stuck to find set $(x,y,m,n,k).$ It's hard to me to solve equation system.

I truly wish you can give me some hints, no matter on whether this inequality is true, or on where I can find the correct proof, or on whether the ''mistakes'' I found is right.

Thank you. Any comments and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.**

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{5a + 8}{b + c}} \right)^2\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (5a + 8)^2(b + c)\left((4 \sqrt{13} - 13)a + 13\right)^3\right)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \left[\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (5a + 8)\left((4 \sqrt{13} - 13)a + 13\right)\right]^3.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left[\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (5a + 8)\left((4 \sqrt{13} - 13)a + 13\right)\right]^3\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (5a + 8)^2(b + c)\left((4 \sqrt{13} - 13)a + 13\right)^3\right)(2 + 2\sqrt{13})^2. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: +1. The author posted strong inequalities which is not easy at all.